# 2000 Honda accord

Tags: honda, starting, accord

My car will starts fine sounds normal I turn it off and then it won’t start. Again it sounds like it’s going to turn over but it doesn’t. I let it sit for awhile and it starts. Nothing is wrong with the battery.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it you mean it when it doesn't start again you hear the whir of the starter as it turns the engine, yet the engine won't kick over and run? Or does the starter just do nothing? What do you mean by "let it sit for a while"? Is that 5 minutes or 5 hours?

Comment: The car won’t turn over sounds like it’s going to but doesn’t turn over. I called AAA waited a 15 minutes and tried again it started

Comment: What do you mean by "turn over" ... do you mean the engine won't go around and around at all? Or do you mean the engine goes around and around but never starts?

Comment: I would try turning the key to "ignition" (but not start), counting to 5, and then turning it off.  Immediately go back to ignition, count to 5, then off.  Repeat a half dozen times, and THEN try to start.  See if that makes a difference.  Possibly a clogged fuel filter or collapsed/plugged pick-up screen in the tank.  Letting the car sit allows the debris to settle away from the filter and/or screen.  Cycling the key might "prime" the fuel system with  enough pressure to start.  In any case, I would observe fuel pressure/flow while starting to confirm or eliminate that system.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are having an issue related to heat soak or high engine bay temperatures causing the amount of fuel that the ecu is asking the fuel delivery system to dispense not to be sufficient for a hot start. This can be caused by many separate factors such as aftermarket modification, missing or worn insulation, poor quality fuel, and the list goes on. Its a difficult problem to nail down because of the indirect way that each of the variables can influence the engine. In other words, the ecu may be doing exactly what it is programmed to do, based on the data presented from a plethora of sensors in this case, so no check engine light is present. One example could be rerouting of exhaust components after a turbo upgrade where the new exhaust is placed closer to the intake manifold. While the car is moving and heated air is evacuating from the engine bay the intake manifold stays cool, but when parked the temps rise and when you try and start the car the gasoline, when injected, hits a hot surface, it evaporates, and won't ignite. After 10-15 minutes the temps fall and it will start. That's just one scenario. In that case, if the hot-start enrichment fuel map is influenced by the coolant temp sensor, it wont modify the amount of fuel because the manifold is hotter because its not monitoring those temps for that reason....you can see then how while everything is technically working you could have a problem. More specific information like any aftermarket mods, driving style, location, recent repairs may make receiving the answer that works for you a bit faster. good luck and I hope you get rolling again soon.